# Logistic regression using Longitudinal Data

Tags: regression, logistic, longitudinal-data-analysis

I want to know the factors affecting stunting status among children. My data was taken from year 2003 data and the same children in year 2011. So my data was a longitudinal data. I want to know which factors makes the children become stunted. My dependent variable is stunting status (0=normal, 1=stunted) and my independent variables were socio-demographic and feeding practices (based from their young age 2003) (all categorical variables). Can anyone help?

Comment: Do you only have 2 time points

Comment: Yes Oliver. I only have 2 time points because the data was not really design for the time periods since there is no treatment effect. I only want to  know the factors that affect to this children for being stunted while taking to account the time periods.

Comment: Could individuals in 2003 that were stunted and become normal...or can they only go from normal to stunted.